# Grails - Heroku not using the database defined in DataSource.groovy

Tags: postgresql, grails, heroku

I have just deployed my Grails app on to Heroku by following docs.. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-grails#prerequisites

Before deploying I created a Dev Database and inserted the URL details into the production section of `DataSource.groovy`

```
production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            //url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            //url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp"


            uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL?:"postgres://myuser:mypassword@someAWSmachine:5432/myapp")

            url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + uri.host + ":" + uri.port + uri.path
            username = uri.userInfo.split(":")[0]
            password = uri.userInfo.split(":")[1]
```

however when I deloy out my application, it created another dev database and set this URL information of this new database into the settings under
`Settings` -> `Config Variables` -> `DATABASE_URL`

somehow my app runs and is using this newly created database and it's settings, my question is HOW?  Why would my app not be failing to run, that fact I have a different database URL configured in my `DataSource.groovy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops... I didn't quite digest this line the first time I read it

`uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL?:"postgres://myuser:mypassword@someAWSmachine:5432/myapp")`

Note the `System.env.DATABASE_URL?` ternary operator.

I'll leave this question here for others